# Cannot resolve method putExtra

Tags: android

I am working through an app in Android Studio that passes data using intent for school. I have created my object to pass the data through and started the `Intent` but I keep getting a warning that my `putExtra` method cannot be resolved. Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ContactInfo contactobject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    contactobject = (ContactInfo)extra.get("contact");
    if (contactobject == null )
        contactobject = new ContactInfo();

    TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name1);
    name1.setText(contactobject.getOneName());

    TextView phone1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Phone1);
    phone1.setText(contactobject.getOnePhone());

    TextView email1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Email1);
    email1.setText(contactobject.getOneEmail());

    TextView kin1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Kin1);
    kin1.setText(contactobject.getOneKin());

    TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name2);
    name2.setText(contactobject.getTwoName());

    TextView phone2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Phone2);
    phone2.setText(contactobject.getTwoPhone());

    TextView email2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Email2);
    email2.setText(contactobject.getTwoEmail());

    TextView kin2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Kin2);
    kin2.setText(contactobject.getTwoEmail());

}


public void EditPrimary(View view)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Edit1.class);
    Intent intent = intent1.putExtra("contact", contactobject);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

}
```

Comment: public void EditPrimary(View view)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  
    intent1.putExtra("contact", contactobject);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points:

**Point 1:** don't need to assign `intent1.putExtra("contact", contactobject);` value to other variable

**Point 2:** Your `ContactInfo` Class **must implements class [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)** while you are passing it through an `Intent`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable) to learn how to make a Class `Parcelable`.

I am sure you are missing second point.

Comment: Thanks I made ContactInfo Parcelable and it likes that. This is the first time I have ran into this so I will need to dig into how that works a little more.

Comment: see these links, may help you..https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class-2.html, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the putExtra call to a new intent variable:

```
public void EditPrimary(View view)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Edit1.class);
    intent1.putExtra("contact", contactobject);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Number;
etNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
Number = Integer.parseInt(etNumber.getText().toString());
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Result.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Number",Number);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)